Problem: How to scrape dynamically loaded data table in Python?
Python novice here. I have been learning how to scrape from various baseball sites (Fangraphs, Statcast, Rotowire). I have had success with a few different methods, but the Park Factors table on Statcast is giving me issues. I have tried using Selenium and I have tried saving a local html copy of the site on my computer to practice on without repeatedly sending requests to the Statcast server.  The below script does scrape a table on the URL, but it’s the first I think, just a game score.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

# Set your user agent information
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "FirstName LastName <myemail@email.com>"
}

# Set the URL of the webpage containing the park factors
url = "https://baseballsavant.mlb.com/leaderboard/statcast-park-factors?type=year&year=2024&       
batSide=L&stat=index_wOBA&condition=All&rolling="

# Initialize the WebDriver (e.g., for Firefox)
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# Navigate to the URL
driver.get(url)

# Wait for the table to be loaded (adjust the timeout as needed)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "table")))

# Extract the table data
table = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "table")
table_html = table.get_attribute("outerHTML")

# Use pandas to read the HTML table
df = pd.read_html(StringIO(table_html))[0]

# Close the WebDriver
driver.quit()

# Display the DataFrame
print(df)

I want to scrape the larger “Park Factors” table that lists all the team stadiums and has stats for elements such as "wOBACon" and "BACON". I have attempted this by referring to “table” tag and it never seems to recognize that table. I have attempted indexing the tables but it send me an error that my index is out of range. I have also attempted using ID instead of TAG_NAME and referencing “parkFactors” to no avail. It just says it finds no object with that attribute (does not recognize a table that exists). I have tried to get around that by increasing the length of time it implicitly waits for the dynamically-loaded table to load, without success). I have also attempted referring to class “article-template” and “table-savant” tags with no luck. Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

The data is inside <script> element so to get it you can use re/json modules:
import json
import re

import pandas as pd
import requests

url = "https://baseballsavant.mlb.com/leaderboard/statcast-park-factors?type=year&year=2024&%20%20%20%20%20%20%20batSide=L&stat=index_wOBA&condition=All&rolling="

response = requests.get(url)
data = re.search(r"data = (.*);", response.text).group(1)
data = json.loads(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# print(df)
df["index_woba"] = df["index_woba"].astype(int)

out = df[["venue_name", "index_woba"]].sort_values(
    by=["index_woba", "venue_name"], ascending=[False, True]
)
print(out)

Prints:
                     venue_name  index_woba
10                  Coors Field         113
24             Globe Life Field         105
14     Great American Ball Park         105
4              Kauffman Stadium         105
26               Nationals Park         103
7                 Rogers Centre         102
20                  Truist Park         102
0                 Angel Stadium         101
15                Busch Stadium         101
22           Citizens Bank Park         101
9                 Wrigley Field         101
11               Dodger Stadium         100
17             Minute Maid Park         100
12                     PNC Park         100
27                 Target Field         100
16               loanDepot park         100
8                   Chase Field          99
18                Comerica Park          99
2         Guaranteed Rate Field          99
1   Oriole Park at Camden Yards          99
28               Yankee Stadium          99
13        American Family Field          98
5              Oakland Coliseum          97
6               Tropicana Field          97
25                   Citi Field          96
19                  Oracle Park          96
3             Progressive Field          96
21                   Petco Park          95
23                T-Mobile Park          93

